# CORS 'Allow-Credentials' Nodejs/Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cors, xmlhttprequest

My project is running on Node with an Express backend.

I'm trying to query my Arango database clientside with Arangojs. ArangoDB is running on Docker on Digital Ocean. I have no issues querying my database serverside, however I get the following error on page load:

> Failed to load
>   http://0.0.0.0:8529/_db/database/_api/cursor: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is 'false'
>   which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.
>   Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The
>   credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is
>   controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

My code on the clientside js looks like this:

```
var db = new arangojs.Database({url:'http://0.0.0.0:8529'})
db.useDatabase(dbase)
db.useBasicAuth("database", 'password')
db.query('FOR doc IN docs RETURN doc') // etc. etc.
```

**EDIT:** 1 year later in hindsight this question is pretty silly - The correct answer for this is don't expose your database credentials through clientside JS... Communicate with your backend, and have that communicate with your datastore.

Comment: _My code on the clientside js looks like this:_. Really ? you are connecting to db on client side ?

Comment: you should try connecting db from server side I think the problem will be resolved

Comment: @UsmanRana yes to the API

Comment: one thing to note is that when sending Allow-Credentials true, you can't Allow-Origin *

Comment: @jayf93. that's not how this works. you should make a connection to the db on server side and send request for data to the server.

Comment: i see, still learning all this stuff @UsmanRana, thanks for the advice. How could I go about that with ExpressJS?

Comment: there you go https://expressjs.com/en/guide/database-integration.html

Comment: @UsmanRana, can you re-submit what you posted as an answer instead of a comment? I'd like to accept your answer as this was quite helpful

Answer (score 17):

You are configuring `cors()` wrong, you have to use `credentials` property in order to configure **Access-Control-Allow-Credentials**:

```
var cors = require('cors');
var corsOptions = {
    origin: '*',
    credentials: true };

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

Besides that, your `app.all(* ...` isnt necessary because `app.use(cors(corsOptions));` will already handle it for you.

Comment: Does setting origin to * really work with credentials? Shouldn't requests with the credentials flag be blocked if Access-Control-Allow-Origin is set to *? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSNotSupportingCredentials

Comment: If you configure `origin: "*"` the credentials mechanism won't work. If you want credentials to work, you must specify an exact http origin(s). For example: `origin: 'https://www.google.com'` or an array with multiple origins: `origin: [a, b, c]`

Comment: This saves my day. Thanks. I can confirm that origin: "*" won't work. 
Thanks !

Comment: can confirm that "*" is not working

Answer (score 7):

You must set origin with a "trusted" URL or an array of "trusted" URLs, each with protocol + domain + port when, you configure cors with credentials. origin : '*' is blocked, because using credentials for every origin is too permissive. It is like not using credentials at all.