# cors error when setting withCredentials as true

Tags: node.js, reactjs

reactjs code

```
import axios from 'axios';
import {useEffect,useState} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import React from "react";

const App = () => {
    const [res,setRes] = useState(null);
    useEffect(()=>{
        document.cookie="hello1=haha";
        axios.get('http://localhost:4000/hello',{withCredentials:true}).then(res1 => {
            console.log(res1.data)
            setRes(res1.data)
        })
    })

    return (
        <div>
            {res}
        </div>
    );

}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
        <App />
);
```

nodejs code

```
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser'

const PORT = 4000;
const app = express();

const corsOptions = {
    origin: '*',
    credentials: true }

// cors
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(cookieParser())


app.get('/hello', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.cookies);
    res.send('This is from server!')

})


app.listen(PORT, () => {

    console.log('listening on port', PORT); // eslint-disable-line no-console
});
```

From server I am able to print the cookie.
But for client, I got issue on on CORS Error and unable to receive response from server.
How to resolve that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49189058/cors-allow-credentials-nodejs-express

Comment: @traynor saw that answer, and it has already incorporated in code if you check

Comment: check the comments in the first answer and the second answer

Answer (score 0):

The CORS error tells you where the problem lies:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The **Same Origin Policy** disallows reading the remote resource at ‘http://localhost:4000/hello’. (Reason: **Credential is not supported** if the CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ is ‘*’).

In short, you need to define the `origin` when using cookies.

Working example [here](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/cors-with-creds) (on a side note, you'll want to utilize an ENV for the origin (on the client and server), instead of hard-coding it). Run `yarn dev` or `npm run dev` to run example.